# jquery mobile list view pagination using json result set

Tags: jquery, mobile, cordova

I am using jquery mobile and phonegap.

Here is my json result set getting from server and put into the global variable.

```
var categoriesArr = [
            {    
            "Categories": "Bengali Products",        
            "desc": [{"code":"40740","product":"Alphonso Mango Jam 300 Gms","rate":"54.00"}]                                
            },
        {    
        "Categories": "Beverages (Town)",        
            "desc":  [{"code":"40011","product":"Badam Powder 100grams","rate":"30.00"}]                            
            }           
        ];
```

If you click on one category, it will show the category description(desc) which contain more than 100 records.

Using this result set, how to paginate(10 per page) the categories in list view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is kind of vague - is this what you need?

```
var len = categoriesArr.length;
for(var i = 0 ; i < len ; i++){
    //do something with categoriesArr[i].Categories (could write to DOM)
    console.log(categoriesArr[i].Categories);
    for(var x in categoriesArr[i].desc[0]){
        //do something with categoriesArr[i].desc[0][x] (could write to DOM)
        console.log(x + ": " + categoriesArr[i].desc[0][x]);
    }
}
```

I log the results to the web console, but please feel free to do whatever you wish.

To paginate you should look at [FilamentGroup's Mobile Pagination Plugin](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_mobile_pagination_plugin/)

**Edit After Your Comment**

Do you mean the desc arrays contain more than one element, a la:

```
var categoriesArr = [
            {    
            "Categories": "Bengali Products",        
            "desc": [{"code":"40740","product":"Alphonso Mango Jam 300 Gms","rate":"54.00"}, {"code":"1337","product":"jordanarseno","rate":"Free"}]                                
            },
        {    
        "Categories": "Beverages (Town)",        
            "desc":  [{"code":"40011","product":"Badam Powder 100grams","rate":"30.00"}]                            
            }           
        ];
```

If so, iterate over the desc array instead of assuming zero index:

```
for(var i = 0, len = categoriesArr.length ; i < len ; i++){
    //do something with categoriesArr[i].Categories (could write to DOM)
    console.log(categoriesArr[i].Categories);
    for(var j = 0, dlen = categoriesArr[i].desc.length ; j < dlen ; j++){
        for(var x in categoriesArr[i].desc[j]){
            //do something with categoriesArr[i].desc[j][x] (could write to DOM)
            console.log(x + ": " + categoriesArr[i].desc[j][x]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thans for u r reply. But i want to paginate over description field(des) for each category, which contain more than 100 records in the json result set.

Comment: Thank u , But how to restrict the results 5 or 10 per page. And once Click on the 'next' button, it will show the another 5 0r 10 results.

Comment: I don't have experience using the pagination plugin that was linked above, but after reading the home page, I'd guess you should be able to get it working by referencing local `href`'s inside your <a> tags that point to pageID's instead of absolute .html URLs. Something like `<li class="ui-pagination-prev"><a href="#page1">Prev</a></li>`. In your loops above, wrap the content in divs with the unique pageID's. You'll have to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve your problem with [JQuery table sorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/).

It supports sorting, and pagination when [pager](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html) is included.

Comment: But i need to display results in list view using jquery mobile for Android.

Comment: Sorry missed the "mobile" part.